# php pagination with action buttons

Tags: php, mysql

I have following PHP page which queries MYSQL TABLE and displays the result.

```
    <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="PASSWORD"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="syslog"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="logs"; // Table name
    // Connect to server and select databse
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    //$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY `LOGS` datetime LIMIT 0 , 10";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `logs`\n"
        . "ORDER BY `logs`.`datetime` DESC LIMIT 0, 50 ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    // Define $host_column=1
    echo '<table width="1400" border="1" align="left" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">';
    echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Host</th><th>Date</th><th>Info</th><th>Type</th><th>Messgae</th></tr>';
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //$host_column assign here from result
    $host_column=$rows['host'];
// show alternate colors based on colum result
    $priority_column=$rows['priority'];
    if($priority_column=='err'){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#FFA07A'><td>".$rows['seq']."</td><td>".$rows['host']."</td><td>".$rows['datetime']."</td><td>".$rows['priority']."</td><td>".$rows['program']."</td><td>".$rows['msg']."</td></tr>";
    }else if($host_column=='10.0.0.1'){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#bbbbbb'><td>".$rows['seq']."</td><td>".$rows['host']."</td><td>".$rows['datetime']."</td><td>".$rows['priority']."</td><td>".$rows['program']."</td><td>".$rows['msg']."</td></tr>";
    }else if($host_column=='10.0.0.2'){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#cccccc'><td>".$rows['seq']."</td><td>".$rows['host']."</td><td>".$rows['datetime']."</td><td>".$rows['priority']."</td><td>".$rows['program']."</td><td>".$rows['msg']."</td></tr>";
    }
    }
    echo '</table>';
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

The results are in thousands, therefore I wanted to have per page result with next page option including how many pages are there , next previous. Also I would like to have an action button on each row , like DELETE , EDIT and when I click on it, it should perform an action of my choice like goto another php with action delete/edit this entry number. I done pagination with simple page, but integrating part is where I am failing plus adding action buttons (or text)

Comment: Just google or search in the community "pagination", I've personally answered at least 5 similar questions regarding this matter.
Another note, you're using mysql_* which is **deprecated**, you should use mysqli_ or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing the pagination on the SQL side, by passing pageIndex and pageRecordCount.

`... LIMIT {pageIndex * pageRecordCount}, {pageRecordCount}`